# I want this question to be unlocked

Tags: discussion

Or... if any mod sees this, please state the reason why it should remain locked.

Comment: The lock is for the mods to sort out what's going on. It will be unlocked eventually.

Comment: I'm new to the discussion and the issue, and you attack me for being uninterested? I think you are taking the whole thing FAR too personally and getting overly sensitive. I'm here to help you.

Comment: I'm one of the mods ...

Comment: we have side channels for us to use  - trust us, we are trying to figure this out

Answer (score 6):

The lock was in the main to sort out the rollback/edit war you were having with the community, and to stop you writing offensive comment into the post. If you can refrain from doing that, then I can unlock the post.

Based on the offensive nature of your communication in the post and the DMZ, I have been more than happy to keep the lock on the post. Be aware that we do not take kindly to offensive words and outright insults.